# Evento OnClick solo me funciona una vez

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, click

tengo un evento que ejecuto un button, pero solo me funciona una vez, luego no me vuelve a cambiar el estado.

```
 const [colorClick, setColorClick] = useState('gray')
    const [yearClick, setyearClick] = useState('')


      const handleChangeYear = e =>{
        setyearClick(year)
        setColorClick('purple')
      }

 return (
       
               
                  

 <li className="m-1">  
      <button onClick={handleChangeYear}
          style={{backgroundColor:`${colorClick}`}}>
                 {year}<span className="ml-1 text-indigo-200"></span>
       </button>
 </li>
```

Es decir, el primer click que hago en el boton si que me cambia a 2022 o 2021, pero al volver a hacer click ya no me cambia el valor

Comment: deberías agregar la tag de react, y quizá algún ejemplo del componente completo? hay muy poca información para saber porqué pasa eso, por ejemplo no se sabe de dónde viene year, o cómo estás tratando de hacer la modificación

Comment: Prueba ejecutando una arrow function anonima en tu evento click: `onClick={()=>{handleChangeYear}}`

Comment: Y de donde viene year? o que es o hace year?
Porque al hacer setYear le pasas una variable year, si ese valor es el mismo en cada set React no volverá a hacer el render del componente. Te sugiero leer [ask] y sería ideal que envíes lo que se conoce como mínimo código verificable, para poder entender lo que intentas hacer y probarlo a efectos de ayudarte lo más rápido posible.

Comment: El nombre del evento onclick tiene que ir todo en minúscula. 
Tampoco se puede ver claro donde esta el fallo ya que falta parte de la función que tienes escrita donde return no esta claro que devuelve...